# How to carry out population-mean cosinor analysis in R using 'card' package

Tags: r, cosine-similarity, card, temporal, amplitude

I'm get an error message when trying to run a population-mean cosinor model using the 'card' package in R and am not sure how to fix it.

I have individual level data of mean physical activity energy expenditure (PAEE) per hour, collected over six days (example dataset below).

I want to quantify how the daily temporal physical activity pattern differs for different groups of individuals in my sample (e.g. for different age groups).

As time is cyclical, I think the most appropriate model to investigate this is a population-mean cosinor model as this will allow me to compare model parameters (MESOR, amplitude, acrophase) between groups.

Example data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), 
    Hour = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), PAEE_per_hr = c(0.416045904159546, 
    0.0906371846795082, 0.106075316667557, 0.169953748583794, 
    1.06217288970947, 3.3313889503479, 1.26075291633606, 49.9070358276367, 
    105.634162902832, 96.9463958740234, 53.8996658325195, 35.7408714294434, 
    61.3463325500488, 54.0382881164551, 51.7777862548828, 84.1668243408203, 
    39.2428550720215, 63.6116409301758, 56.1053810119629, 31.6829490661621, 
    33.3736877441406, 22.2731056213379, 22.8102855682373, 20.4649925231934, 
    6.55480527877808, 1.01683390140533, 0.463269412517548, 0.499143779277802, 
    0.680253326892853, 6.76072216033936, 13.4914741516113, 21.9464359283447, 
    44.773868560791, 105.971572875977, 103.113182067871, 90.8871612548828, 
    112.658706665039, 99.4749526977539, 84.9520721435547, 101.361457824707, 
    59.5359306335449, 88.0693435668945, 86.4329681396484, 72.5385208129883, 
    22.752025604248, 41.6730079650879, 48.6468772888184, 38.3001899719238, 
    0.780587673187256, 0.308294117450714, 2.24866938591003, 1.10028839111328, 
    9.54257297515869, 66.5246429443359, 187.857177734375, 145.543869018555, 
    106.262771606445, 125.721298217773, 113.755531311035, 89.0944900512695, 
    63.3436241149902, 61.8305015563965, 48.7287330627441, 68.1324768066406, 
    50.5940742492676, 36.8570556640625, 61.684757232666, 104.92928314209, 
    39.1712417602539, 31.3020153045654, 18.2132987976074, 1.21512508392334
    )), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Population mean cosinor model

```
library(card)
m <- cosinor(PAEE_per_hr ~ Hour, data = data, tau = c(24), population = "ID")
```

Error message

Error in data.frame(population = rep(names(kfits), sapply(kfits, length)),  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 24